# Stream http JPEG video in Android

Tags: android, http, video-streaming, jpeg, exoplayer

Recently, **i'm trying to stream JPEG video (not MJPEG) from an ip camera**. (model of the camera https://www.iodata.jp/product/lancam/lancam/ts-wrlp/)
I want to stream http which return JPEG video without audio, but can't find any library which support JPEG vide. I've tried exo and it works fine with H264 and MJPEG, but it can not decode JPEG.
Is there anyway i can stream this type of video (JPEG). Do i misunderstand something?

Thank you guys

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"video JPEG" IS a MJPEG (Motion). url in row with HTTP/JPEG format points probably on address with last taken image (last frame from MJPEG) and every time you refresh page then image changes, OR it is a web site which refreshes automatically presenting last JPEG (so in fact this isn't a video, its a simple web app). even last part of url is suggesting that this is only last **snapshot** image

in both options above - JPEG frame/picture isn't a video "playable" by any video player, sooner you will get this image (autorefreshing?) using `WebView`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i dont think the http url is only a snapshot. I've try the link in normal web browers like Chrome, Opera,... it plays the video. But it seems strange because the web page will be loading continuously.

Comment: well, even in URL there is a "snapshot" keyword... if this web page is loading continuously then it means it is probably self-reloading or running some JS refreshing static JPEG. thats may only clue, for shure there is no "video JPEG" format (well, there is, MJPEG, which is separately listed)